# Get unreadable string from GPS tracker

Tags: string, binary, gps, hex, decoding

I'm getting this unreadable string from a GPS tracking device and I need to decode these information so I can use it in my application (c#).

```
$A  grQ05Ah@‘)���ÿÿûÿÿ����°#~À‚¡U
```

But in fact what i expect is something like below :

```
*HQ,XXXXXX,41,4#V1,time,A,**Lat**,N/S,**Lng**,W/E,000.00,000,date,FFFFFBFF,432,35,32448,334
```

How can i convert the string to standard format in c# ?

I convert data to byte as you can see :

```
24-41-20-20-67-72-51-30-35-41-68-40-91-29-3F-3F-3F-FF-FF-FB-FF-FF-3F-3F-3F-3F-B0-23-7E-C0-82-A1-55
```

Comment: Depends on the encoding of the bytes that you get from the network. Use the appropriate Encoding class and construct your string based on that.

Comment: Where do you get the string from? This seems like a problem with compression. Maybe you need to decompress it i.e. with `GzipStream` or something similar.

Comment: @ManoDestra I get the data from gps  ,i test all of the encoding but it didn't work

Comment: @GeorgJung i get the data from gps i.e avl device ,i use ascci and utf8 and default encoding but it didn't work

Comment: Indeed - documentation would be your friend here.

Comment: Where's your code? How are you "converting" the data to bytes? It should already be a byte stream...

Comment: @kumaDK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375499/data-from-gps-sometimes-changed-to-unreadable-format

Comment: @kumaDK the gps device every times sends its log to my server,so i just listen to the port and save the data,but when i move the avl device the data is changed to unreadable string

Comment: You don't reveal until now that the data comes in as expected sometimes? Come on!

Comment: If you want to know you can give me an ip and port to send this data to your server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really some binary information and If you have clearly read out the product manual then it says formation of this binaries.

Converting the data to hex will give something like this..

```
24-41-20-20-67-72-51-30-35-41-68-40-91-29-3F-3F-3F-FF-FF-FB-FF-FF-3F-3F-
```

And then you need to refer the manual for exact meaning of these hex numbers

ex--(in some chinese devices)

```
2 bytes(24),  stand for standard mode
10 bytes,  is device'ID (41 20 20 67 72)
6 bytes, is time 
6 bytes, is data
8 bytes, is latitude
2 bytes, battery like this 06= 100% 05=80% 04=60% 03=40% 02=20% 01=10%
10 bytes is  longitude
```

** You are receiving these binaries because you've asked it to send the info in binary mode.

Comment: You said the 6 byte after device id is time ,51-30-35 .what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how your string initially was encoded. But basic idea is using transform functions with required parameters.

You can use [Encoding.GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3(v=vs.100).aspx)  method of appropriate encoding.

For example if you know that original string was encoded in `UTF-8` format before being transmitted to you, you may convert it to the string as

`string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesReceived);`

Comment: again it returns the orginal value

Comment: byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("$A  grQ05Ah@‘)���ÿÿûÿÿ����°#~À‚¡U");
           
            string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ba);

Comment: Use same encoding for getting bytes too. Again, your example is valid *only* if you know byte array is UTF-8 data.