# Where are the lat and long in this gps string?

Tags: gps, position, latitude-longitude, tracking

Can anyone tell which are the latitude and longitude in this gps tracking string ?

`*hq,35632708012xxxx,VP1,V,226,001,42020,28871,0Y42020,14583,30Y42020,28872,13#`

Position should be in Romania if it helps.

**Edit:** it is from a chinese GPS tracker purchased from eBay, it looks like attached image.

The data string is what I got sent to my server.
It works crappy, for example if I send command "GOOGLE" should returna  google link but it returns a text advertisement in Chinese that contains something like "free shipping" :/

From what I asked around the protocol is similar to "H02", but it looks like I am missing some "N"/"S" between the numbers that should be the lat/long positon, so I am confused.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a message with a predefined pattern for a certain protocol. Actually it looks familiar to me but I don't remember from where. can you please explain where did you get that string? was it from a certain gps device? In addition, this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380404/get-unreadable-string-from-gps-tracker

Comment: I added some details, the protocol seems "H02" but doesn't contain "N" or "S" between the lat/long numbers.

Comment: You're right, it seems like a modification of H02 protocol. It might be some proprietary protocol of theirs and therefore cannot be parsed unless we know the details